# Android Emulator Issue - Google Account Dialog gets squeezed to the top

Tags: android, android-emulator

Google Account Dialog (remove and/or add) gets squeezed to the top in the notification bar. The following example displays Pixel_2 (Android 8.2/API Level 28). But the issue happens on all android version and api levels.

The issue is driving me nuts. It doesn't happen on actual device though. Wondering if anyone else seen this issue before? and have found any potential solution or workaround.

Logged ticket on Google issue tracker -> https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/129478249

**Menu -> Settings:**

[image]

And in the below image (4) you can see the dialog being squeezed to the top and if you click and drag the notification bar you can see the remove account dialog in the background:

[image]

I'm using Ubuntu 18.10 on a Virtual Machine.

**Here is my Virtual Machine settings:**

[image]

Comment: what this question have to do in here?

Comment: For a solution. Why do you think this question should not be here?

Comment: did you mention anywhere where it is supposed to be.. like here https://developer.android.com/studio/report-bugs.html ? There is special services for mentioning issue, and SO is not definitely the place for bug and issue tracking..

Comment: I agree, this is not a bug reporting place. But the reason why I asked this question is to see if anyone else have had a similar issue and probably have a potential solution or workaround. Updated the question with the bug I reported on Android Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the comment in  https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/129478249

> This is an known issue with the outer virtual machine's GL drivers. Recommend using `-gpu swiftshader_indirect`.

**Here is how you can change it on the android emulator:**

[image]

**After Fix:**

[image]